# variance of an integral of the sum of lognormal random variable

Tags: calculus

(My first post here. If anything is wrong or unclear, please let me know.)

This arises when I attempted to price an option with a jump diffusion. Here is the specific variance I am trying to solve:

$$\operatorname{Var}\left(\int_0^T \, \sum_0^{N(t)} \ln\big(K(t)+1\big) \, dt \, \mid \, N(T)\right)$$

where

$$\ln\big(K(t) + 1\big) \sim N \Big(\ln\left(\overline{ K} +1\right)-0.5 \sigma^2, \sigma^2\Big)$$

$$E\big(K(t)\big)=\overline{ K}$$

Here, $\,K(t)\,$ is the random variable (percentage jump). $\,N(t)\,$ is the number of jumps until time $t$, following a poisson distribution with intensity $\lambda$ . Appreciate any help. Thanks! :)